# How to get an output in groupwise format and export the same format in a csv file?

Tags: r, data.table

I need an output in a group-wise format with the group's name coming in every start.

```
dt <- data.table(
                 Type    = c("t","t", "c", "c", "c"),
                 Time    = c("pre", "post", "pre", "post", "pre"),
                 Student = c(6,6,6,7,7),
                 RollNum1 = c(49,69,44,86,39),
                 Marks1= c(8,9,10,8,5))
```

I want to group the above table by `Type` and `Time` variable and get the output in below format while exporting in csv format

[image: Output in single sheet and row-wise]

I tried using split

```
dt_split <- split(dt, by = c("Type", "Time"))
```

but the output doesn't have the custom `group` and `time` name' and when I export to csv the output doen't come in proper format.

Comment: Have you tried `lapply(names(dt_split), function(nm) write.csv(dt_split[[nm]], paste0(nm, ".csv'))`

Comment: Hi @akrun, the code splits the data into 4 different files. I actually wanted the data to be in the same sheet but differentiated by headers

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for seems not to be a proper CSV (which would have the same number of fields on each row), but I assume you're targeting to import your file in Excel afterwards.

You should be able to get away with doing so by using the `append` argument like so:

```
f = tempfile()
dt[ , {
if (.GRP == 1L) {
  fwrite(.SD[0L], f)
}
cat(paste(sprintf('%s=%s', names(.BY), unlist(.BY)), collapse = '; '),
    '\n', sep = '', file = f, append = TRUE)
fwrite(.SD, f, append = TRUE)
}, by = .(Group = Type, Time)]
cat(readLines(f), sep = '\n')
# Student,RollNum1,Marks1
# Group=t; Time=pre
# 6,49,8
# Group=t; Time=post
# 6,69,9
# Group=c; Time=pre
# 6,44,10
# 7,39,5
# Group=c; Time=post
# 7,86,8
```

The `.GRP` branch assures we only write column names for the first `by` group. Besides that, for each group, we first write the "group info", then write the remaining data as a normal CSV.

I'm not positive how this will look when imported to Excel; you may need to append a few blank columns to the header rows.

FWIW, unless you've got a specific use case in mind, I would recommend against doing this. The more typical way to write out grouped data would be to use the directory structure of output (partitions) or the file name to signal what the group is, e.g.:

```
out_dir = tempdir()
dt[ , {
  # highly generic -- it will be cleaner and easier to read in your case
  #   to simply write out the directory names using `.BY` for the two groupers
  partition_names = sprintf('%s=%s', names(.BY), unlist(.BY))
  partitions = do.call(file.path, as.list(partition_names))
  out_subdir = file.path(out_dir, partitions)
  dir.create(out_subdir, recursive = TRUE, showWarning = FALSE)
  # timestamp the file write time as a means of logging
  ts = as.integer(Sys.time())
  fwrite(.SD, file.path(out_subdir, sprintf('%d.csv', ts)))
}, by = .(Group = Type, Time)]
list.files(out_dir, recursive = TRUE)
# [1] "Group=c/Time=post/1562500495.csv" "Group=c/Time=pre/1562500495.csv" 
# [3] "Group=t/Time=post/1562500495.csv" "Group=t/Time=pre/1562500495.csv"
```